# sqlite: save array?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have simple table with two columns: "id" INTEGER as a key, and "data" INTEGER.

One of the user's requirement is to save order in which he view data.
So I have to save order of records in table.

The simple solution as I see: id, data, order_id.
But in this case if user add record into the middle of his table's view,
we have to update many records.

Another idea: id, data, next_id, previous_id.
The insertion is fast, but extraction of record in defined order is slow.

So what is the best (fast) method to save order of records in table
using sqlite? fast = fast insert + fast extraction of records in defined order.

Update:
The problem with order_id is as I see in insertion of new record. I expect that we have 10 * 10^3 records. The insertion of new records will in the worst case update of all 10 * 10^3 records. sqlite database file is on flash memory. So it is not as fast as on PC, and will be better reduce "write" size, to increase life time of flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the order_id is better, you only need one update instruction

```
update table
   set order_id = order_id + @newRecordOrder
 where id = @id
   and order_id > @newRecordOrder
```

I do wonder if that order is unique to all the table or to a subset, thus needing a second pk field.

Comment: The problem with order_id as I see, that if we for example we have 5000 of records and insert the 101 records we have to update 4500 records. The sqlite database is in flash. So it is slow as fast as on PC with hard disk.

Comment: Well, I guess then it's more a matter of how frequently you'll insert unsequential ids vs how frequently you'll be searching data ordered by sequence...

Comment: BTW, I don't think you need both previous_id and next_id, with only one would be enough. Also, any insert would mean an update to the record with the next/previous id to point to the inserted record.